# How do I get a Month from LocalDate in JPQL query?

Tags: java-8, jpa-2.1

I got a transaction with a `LocalDate` as `created` attribute:

`private LocalDate created;`

I also got following query to retrieve every date out of my table `transaction`.

`SELECT DISTINCT t.created FROM Transaction t`

This however just gives me all dates and I am mapping those dates to all month that were found.

```
public List<Month> findAllUsesdMonth() {
  return getEm().createNamedQuery(Transaction.FIND_ALL_MONTH, LocalDate.class).getResultList().stream().map(LocalDate::getMonth)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This leads to duplicate month obviously because I selected distinct dates and not distinct months. A workaround would be to use a Set instead of a List.

I would like to retrieve only the month in the JPQL query instead of mapping them afterward. Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: @Saveen Thanks! I should have read more clearly over my querstion before submitting it. :/

Comment: can you add your date-format(save in db) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Date format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Query: `SELECT t FROM Transaction t GROUP BY (SUBSTRING(t.created, 6, 7))`

By calling this `NamedQuery` you will get distinct month.

Comment: I will get the whole transaction with your query and not the Month of a LocalDate.